# How to convert asciimath to latex

Tags: latex, mathjax, asciimath

i am developing a maths portal at some point i need to convert **asciimath** format expression to **latex** format expression. how it will possible ? I am using **mathjax**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP and JS script available in the asciimath repository (under `/asciimath-based`), see https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/tree/master/asciimath-based.

But there's no integration of those tools into MathJax at this time.